# Force to load another store with different currency [Magento 1.7]

Tags: magento, load, magento-1.7, store

I have created module that checks user country based on his IP and now I want to force users from Europe load website_en with store id 2 and US users to load website_us with store id 1.

In index.php I have tried to do:

```
<?php
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

if (in_country() == "EU") {

    Mage::run("website_en ", "store"); 
} 
else if(in_country() == "US")
{
    Mage::run("website_us ", "store"); 
}
else
{
    Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
}
```

...but without any luck.

Comment: Do you different domains or a single domain with multiple stores running on it?

Comment: Thanks I have solved this problem by properly configurating varnish

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I have solved this problem by properly configuring varnish.

Actually this code is working. website is with differents domains.

`in_country` - is code that check users geo info.